# AJAX Call to .NET Core API fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-2.0

My AJAX call to a .NET Core application is not working. On localhost everything was working fine, however after publishing the application to my server the AJAX call is getting a CORS policy error:

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed.

When I use Postman the call is successful. Is this issue related to the server side or client side?

I have tried to check the CORS policy, headers in the AJAX, and everything seems okay

```
$.ajax({
  url: DashboardController + "GetLoggedInUser",
  type: "GET",
  "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: 'json',
  beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + window.localStorage.authorizationData);
  },
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    SetLoggedInUser(data);
    //HFPracticeData.Add("BackEndLogin", "");
    //HFPracticeData.Set("BackEndLogin", asd);
    //backendLogin.DoClick();
  },
```

Server Side Code (Startup.cs)

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
  options.AddPolicy("AllowAllHeaders", builder =>
  { 
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
  });
});
```

CORS issue should not occur.

Comment: The issue is in your C# code which is adding the headers to the response, not the JS/jQuery. If you can show us that code we can help you more effectively.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan How Postman is getting the response fine?

Comment: Because CORS only applies to browser-based requests.

Comment: yes, so what should I share ? Startup.cs has the CORS policy settings. I am adding the code in the question.

Comment: You need to add the relevant code which places the CORS headers in the response. I can't tell you where that is exactly as I don't know your project.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan code is added please review question.

Answer (score 0):

OK found the solution:
 The problem was with the Response Header, as error states

```
    The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 
    '*, *', but only one is allowed.
```

'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' was adding multiple times, so I removed 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' response header from IIS Server site. Now its working fine.